# Scala: How to make toString() take an implicit parameter?

Tags: scala, implicit

I would like to be able to have a case class like this:

```
case class TxtFrag(start:Int, end:Int){
  override def toString()(implicit src:String) = src.substring(start, end)
}
```

so that I can do something like this:

```
implicit val sourceText = "FooBar"
println(TxtFrag(0, 3)) // should print "Foo"
```

But, understandably, the compiler complains that my `toString` function does not override anything. Could there be any clever workaround to make this work, without making `TxtFrag` any heavier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You could put the implicit parameter on the class itself? e.g.

```
case class TxtFrag(start:Int, end:Int)(implicit src:String) {
   override def toString() = src.substring(start, end)
}
```

What is it you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am processing some very long text, and need a lightweight case class to hold gazillions of references to small fragments of the text. If I added a reference in the class itself, that would increase memory use unnecessarily, since all are fragments of the same text.

Comment: It's just a reference to the same text, not a copy. But sure. All I can suggest is using a custom method (e.g. `stringValue`, and then calling `println(TxtFrag(0, 3).stringValue))` - you can't change the interface of the built-in `toString`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have now. What sucks is that when the `TxtFrag`s are inside other classes, I have to write custom `stringValue` functions for them too.

Comment: You can avoid most of the repetition of that by using a typeclass approach with "deriving", e.g. scalaz `Show` and [shapeless-scalaz](https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-contrib). Just make the `Show` instance for `TxtFrag` depend on the `implicit src`.